# What groups can I safely refer to, to demonstrate various theorems in a first course in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When studying abstract algebra, I do prefer having a nice simple and concrete example to demonstrate the theorem/lemma.

However, the 'first course' book that I am currently learning from often uses (in my opinion) quite complicated examples to demonstrate the theorem/lemma. Sometimes this is fine, but other times I may as well be reading Chinese.

For example, my 'go-to' group for an infinite abelian group is $\left ( \mathbb{Z}, + \right )$. My 'go-to' group for a finite abelian group is $\left ( \mathbb{Z_n}, + \right )$

What are some nice and easy-to-understand

1. Non-abelian finite groups
2. Non-abelian infinite groups

that I could use to demonstrate/test the theorems I learn?

I understand that 'easy' is a subjective term. But I am trusting your expertise as to what would be considered 'easy' for someone first learning abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using groups that can be understood in a geometrical way, and not only by their presentation and abstract definitions. Therefore, groups of symmetries are always good examples.

You could use: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ seen as reflection, the circle $S^1$ seen as a group of rotations, the dihedral groups seen as symmetries of polygons, the symmetric groups $S_n$ as groups of automorphisms of finite sets, and if they have seen a bit of physics you have $SO(3)$ as rotational symmetries and $SO(3,1)$ (proper Lorentz transformations). You could also take a look at lattice groups and so on. All of these are interesting examples because they arise from other concrete problems, and not only as an abstract mathematical construction.

Answer (score 1):

$S_3$ is quite easy to understand and non-abelian, but you should spend some time getting used to it.

It has six elements: the identity, the three transpositions each swapping a pair of elements, and the two "rotations", which rotate the three elements in one direction or in the other.

It's clear what the square of a transposition is, and what the product of two rotations is, but it's less obvious what is the product of a transposition and a cycle, or of two distinct transpositions. Get yourself three distinct objects and play around with them until you understand how it works and can explain intuitively why the multiplication table for $S_3$ is what it is.

Then work out the subgroups, and which of those subgroups are normal.

Answer (score 1):

Semidirect products also give very concrete ways of understanding nonabelian groups. For example, I've always found that the semidirect product decomposition of diheldral groups $D_{2n}$ as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mu_2$, where $\mu_2 = \{\pm 1\}$ always made it much easier to do computations with them.

In this case, it tells you that every element of $D_{2n}$ can be written as $(a,\pm)$, where $a\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Multiplication is given by $(a,-)(b,\pm) = (a-b,\mp)$, and $(a,+)(b,\pm) = (a+b,\pm)$.

Inversion is given by $(a,\pm)^{-1} = (\mp a,\pm)$.

Answer (score 0):

Non-Abelian finite: $D_{2n}$

Non-Abelian Infinite: $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 0):

A couple of non-Abelian infinite groups:

- the multiplicative group of invertible 2x2 matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$
- the free group on 2 generators.

Both are countable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already posted, don't forget that the direct product of two groups is a group, and that lets you put together many more examples.

Also, I don't think anyone mentioned the quaternion group.